# How to retrieve select option?

Tags: php, select

I am calling selected value twice in PHP instead of once.

Please anyone solve my problem??

**Html part:**

```
<select name="mol[]" >
   <option value="">Choose Mode of License</option>
   <option value="standalone">Standalone</option>
   <option value"wan">WAN</option>
   <option value"lan">LAN</option>
</select>
```

**php code:**

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<select name='mol' class='mol'>
     <option value='$row[mol]'>$row[mol]</option>
     <option value='standalone'>Standalone</option>
     <option value='wan'>WAN</option>
     <option value='lan'>LAN</option>
  </select>"; 
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: What you really want to achieve its unclear

Comment: You need to add much more detail about what you are trying to achieve and what you have already tried. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @uchiha if i choose standalone ..In the retrieved list i should get standalone plus the the other two option values(lan, wan) below them..but now i am getting standalone plus standalone,wan,lan

Comment: @learner are you programming on plane php or any other framework like codeigniter or laravel ? If you're using some framework it's easy else it would be little tricky.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478059/how-to-prevent-duplicate-values-in-a-combo-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use loop and generate a select box**

```
    //firs create an array with your options 
    $options[] = array(
    'standalone' => 'Standalone',
    'wan'=>'Wan',
    'lan'=>'Lan'
     );

    //if already selected store the key to a variable 
    $selected = @$row['mol'];

    echo "<select name='mol' class='mol'>";
    //generate select box
    foreach($options as $op => $key)
    {
     if($selected == $op)
      {
         echo " <option value='$op' selected = 'selected'>$key</option>";
      }
     else
      {
         echo " <option value='$op' >$key</option>";
      }
    }
   echo "</select>";
```

Comment: everything is perfect but need to change foreach($options as $op=>$key) to ($options[0] as $op=>$key)....Thanks a lot